# American 1970's movie "DreamScape"? NO plot of aliens, children, monsters, violence, crime, dinosaurs, genetics or time travel

Tags: story-identification, movie

Scientists develop headgear apparatus to record someone's experiences. Other people buy the recordings and wear the apparatus to "feel" the experiences. Example: various adrenaline activities and learning applications. It backfires when a man dies after he "loops" a continuous orgasm. Thought Ellen Burstyn (chain smoker) and William Hurt (NOT Altered States) were in it but nothing matches from their filmographies.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate because this has been accepted as an answer before. Please don't feel that this means this is a bad question, just one we've had before. :) And your details were good enough that I knew the answer before seeing Clara had already answered. Welcome to the site! Don't forget to formally accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This must be *[Brainstorm](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085271/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*, a sci-fi film from 1983 starring Christopher Walken. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorm_(1983_film)):

> Scientists invent a brain–computer interface enabling sensations to be
> recorded from a person's brain and converted to tape for others to
> experience. The team includes estranged husband and wife Michael and
> Karen, as well as Michael's colleague Lillian. At CEO Alex's
> instruction, the team demonstrates the device to investors to gain
> financing...
>
> One team member, Gordy, has sexual intercourse while wearing the
> recorder, and shares the tape with colleagues, including Hal. **Hal
> splices one section of the tape into a continuous orgasm, which
> results in sensory overload,** leading to his forced retirement.
> Tensions increase as the possibilities for abuse become clear.
>
> Suffering from heart problems and a constant cigarette smoker, Lillian
> suffers a heart attack while working alone. Realizing she is about to
> die, Lillian records her experience.

The rest of the film deals with the team trying to access what Lillian saw as she died. She was played by Louise Fletcher (famous for playing Nurse Ratched in *One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest*), rather than Ellen Burstyn,

Comment: One of the better sci-fi films of the era in terms of plausibility. I recall in particular how the recording device starts off extremely large and complex but then Wood's character, an electronics engineer, begins building ever-smaller and more ergonomic versions until it emerges as something like a pair of glasses. Also bonus points for optical recording tape.

Comment: Yeah, it's good movie.  I saw it when it first was in the theater.  A written work that's similar is Clarke's "Patent Pending."